# How do you get the PK for a HyperlinkedIdentityField when going through a Many to Many relationship?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have three models in my Django project:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class OneToTwo(models.Model):
    one = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    two = models.ForeignKey(Model2)
    extra_field_necessitating_intermediate_model = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I am using Django REST Framework to build an API for these models, and I have serializers for Model1 and Model2:

```
class Model1Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ('url', 'name')


class Model2Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = ('url', 'name')
```

... so far, so good. The problem arises when I want to nest a Model2 inside the Model1 serializer. I can create
an intermediary serializer for OneToTwo entities containing the Model2 data:

```
class TwosSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='two.id')
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='two.name')
    class Meta:
        model = OneToTwo
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'name')

class Model2Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    twos = TwosSerializer(source='onetotwo_set', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'twos')
```

... but the `url` field on the `TwosSerializer` is that of the `OneToTwo` entity, not of the related `Model2` entity.
What I want is the `url` field of the internal serializer to be the URL to `Model2.objects.get(pk=two.id)` for
each `two` object in the relationship.

A naive attempt was to create a `url` field definition using the `HyperlinkedIdentityField` class:

```
# this is within the TwosSerializer class above...
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='model2-detail', lookup_value='two.id')
```

... but this results in this error:

```
'OneToTwo' object has no attribute 'two.id'
```

How do I correctly build the URL for an entity that is passing through an intermediate model that I don't want to
expose in the API?

Comment: are you referring to  'lookup_field' , is lookup_value is a typo ?

Comment: Yes, `lookup_value` was a typo, I meant `lookup_field`.